# File path issue in C++ program when executing from a shell script on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, terminal, sh

I've run into a problem on Linux systems that I can't seem to find any concrete solution online for.

I have a C++ application, lets call it `Program1`. `Program1` opens a text file for reading. The text file is in it's parent directory one level up (`../test_file.txt`). So in code, to open the file:

`ifile.open("../test_file.txt");`

If you open a terminal in the same directory as `Program1` and run the executable:

`$ ./Program1 &`

Everything works fine. `test_file.txt` is read without an issue.

Now let's introduce a shell script in a different directory, lets call it `ShellScript1`. This script execute `Program1` and other programs in different directories. The important line the shell script file looks something like this:

`../../test/Release/Program1 &`

When this shell script is ran `Program1` executes but `test_file.txt` cannot be read. Now as far as I can tell this is because the active directory is the directory of the shell script.

I need to be able to run executables with a shell script that doesn't actively change the relative pathing used in the executable such as with `Program1` when ran via shell script.

Is there a way around this? Or is my method of reading in the file in my code need improvement?

Note that I'm running each process as a background process to ensure that I can run each executable simultaneously.

Comment: The path `../test_file.txt` is relative to current working directory, which may or may not be the same directory where the executable resides. If you want a path relative to executable, compute it. Path to executable is usually passed to `main` in `argv[0]`

Comment: @eukaryota Thanks for the link. Since that method spawns a "sub-shell" can I assume that the parent script won't have to wait for the exit of that executable to move on to the next executable? I actually tried a similar method like the one you linked but it didn't work when trying to add the `&` character at the end

Comment: @eukaryota I did consider adding code that checks the current path of the executable and adjusts reading in the file accordingly, but was hoping there was a better, more flexible way.

Comment: In general, this is not a common way to package applications on Linux. Data files are not usually stored with the executable.

Comment: @Barmar I'm assuming the normal Linux method is to store it in some location in the `usr` space or other directory relative to `home`?

Comment: Yes, or hard-code a default location and use an environment variable to override it.

Comment: @Barmar thanks for the clarification. I'll look into it.